# Hiding Script Errors popups in IE8

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, internet-explorer

I have inherited an application that download a js code from another place and with the help of the 
IWebBrowser2 interface in Windows it runs this js in that browser inside a hWindow. 
While i run the app on the machines with IE9 and IE10 no popups with script errors. When  i run the app in a machine with IE8 i can see a script error message appears. I tried to disable the script errors inside the Internet options advanced tab and also cleared the Enable 3-party browser extensions. 
Those didn't help to suppress the script Error. Perhaps, someone knows how i can get rid of the script error in IE8.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Popup appears: An error has occured in the script on this page. I wanted to suppress these kind of popups. So the user won't see them at all. With the method i described above , nothing helped

Comment: This is an unfortunate behaviour of IE < 9 and is best remedied in my opinion by linting your JS code as even trailing/unnecessary commas are a cause of this.  You can use a site like this http://www.jslint.com/ or use a built-in linter for your IDE to catch any potential errors.

Comment: Thanks for the url. But basically you are saying suppose my script has an error and i somehow want to suppress it via settings , i am not able to do so in IE8? i just don't want him to see those popups. Despite the errors in the IE8